# Simple JavaScript XPath syntax pattern validator (no context)?

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, xpath

I've a text field where the user can type a XPath.
I'm just looking for a simple way to validate the XPath pattern so that it's a validate pattern for XML.

I don't have any XSD to check or anything, so I'm guessing a simple regex could be enough.
But i don't really know all the specific of XPath and what is allowed and what isn't.

Tried to look around the net but only found XPath to XSD / XML file validator.

EDIT: I don't want / know what the context will be, I just want to validate the synthax. 
In a nutshell, I'm looking for a `XPathExpression.Compile(String)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Wicked Good XPath: a faster JavaScript XPath library](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2012/09/wicked-good-xpath-faster-javascript.html).

This will implement [document.evaluate()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-evaluate), which will throw [XPathException](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathException) if given an invalid XPath.  There is also a [createExpression()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator-createExpression) function which you might prefer if you do not actually have to evaluate the XPath over a document yet.

(You *really* don't want to use regular expressions to parse XPaths.)

Comment: Thanks however i don't want to "evaluate" the xpath towards a document/context. I just want to validate the synthax of the xpath, not knowing what the document / xsd would be.

Comment: Check out `createExpression()` then.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you, saw it before but thought the resolver couldn't be null. But in fact it can. So i set a try catch method and it seems to work somewhat. However from the page it says it s supposed to return a XPathException but when i try a catch(e if e = "XPathException") it doesn't catch it. As what is thrown is a synthaxException.Not sure if i'm missing something on the catch but that's another question i guess ...

Comment: @TheBakker That's not the correct syntax for `catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Client-side support for XSLT/XPath is pretty inconsistent (they all support it in a fashion, but there's plenty of differences).

If I were you I'd definitely be farming this out to a server-side web service. As an example, in PHP you can use either the [Simple XML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) or [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) classes to run - and, thus, check the validty of - XPath expressions.

Using either of these with arbitrary mark-up you can test if an XPath is valid (or, more correctly, whether the PHP library thinks it is.)

```
$xpath = "foo/bar@"; //<-- invalid XPath
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement("<foo />");
die(@$sxe->xpath('valid@') ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
```

...outputs either "valid" or "invalid", which your AJAX call, which would call the web service, could look for.

Comment: Thanks for your input, however i'm using angular and a java backend, and i'd have liked to let the form validation server side, as to only send valid data to my back end.